# CSS Tooltip Where to put

Tags: html, css

CSS Amateur here.

> EDIT: The problem regarding the focus was already fixed. I just failed to see that there was a space between `:` and `focus` on .."number"]: focus.
>   I have a css for a tooltip but I dont know where to put it and how to make it appear only when a textfield is selected.
>
> Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/274/

```
.tooltip
{
position: absolute;
padding: 1px 10px;
margin-left: 6px;
background: #06DEE5;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
}
```

> I just got the css above from a website by "Inspect element"

Right now, it appears even though the textbox is not selected as seen on the image: http://i.share.pho.to/694c27e9_o.png. I only need the `Please enter name` to appear when that textfield has been selected.

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing it right but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/261/

Comment: I would prefer to use CSS for now. I'm still not that proficient in CSS so jQuery might be a lot to handle.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle you have not included a form tag so the supplied CSS does not work.

To select the tooltip you need the sibling selector `+`. This selector will select the immediately next dom element, and if it matches the rest of the selector, performs the changes as per the css. In this case, we are looking for a sibling with the class of 'tooltip' and changing the background to red:

```
input:focus + .tooltip {
  background:red;
}
```

I have changed the fiddle to include the sibling selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/267/

### Edit

To hide the tool tip until you focus on the element:

Hide the tooltip:

```
.tooltip {
  display:none;
}
```

Show the tool tip on focus:

```
input:focus + .tooltip {
  display:block;
}
```

Updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/269/

Comment: The focus problem is on the textfield itself and I already found a way around it. The remaining problem now is where and how to make the tooltip appear only when a textbox is selected.

Comment: Oh. That was not clear from the question. Add `display:none` to the tooltip, then `display:block` on the focus (as above)

Comment: You can accomplish this with the fiddle provided. Simply set the textbox to display:none and then on focus to display:block (or inline).

Answer (score 0):

you should use "display"

```
.tooltip 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    background: #06DEE5;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #444;
}

form input[type="text"]:focus,
form input[type="number"]: focus,
form input[type="email"]:focus,
form input[type="password"]:focus,
form select:focus,
form textarea:focus
{
    background: #06DEE5;
}

 input:focus + .tooltip {
    display:block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/272/)

CSS:

```
.form-input {
  appearance: none; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: #666;
}

.tooltip {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  cursor: help;  
  padding: 4px 16px;
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
:focus + .tooltip {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{5,100}" required title="At least 5 characters" maxlength="100" name="contact_name" class='form-input' placeholder="Full Name" title="Input your name here." />
<div class="tooltip">Please enter name</div>
```